# Qual melhor maneira de analisar um arquivo muito grande json em java?

Tags: java, json

Eu tenho um arquivo muito grande em json, ele tem 5 gigas e possui 652339 linhas, estava pensando em usar a biblioteca Gson em java.

Gostaria de saber, qual a melhor maneira de analisar de arquivo, já que nem a estrutura do json consegui extrair direito. Exemplo de uma linha do arquivo:

```
{"control": {"lang": {"lang": "pt", "d": 1395183935882, "v": 5}, "last": "UPDATE", "read": {"d": 1395183767992, "v": 3}, "update": {"d": 1395308552817, "v": 2}, "rule": {"entities": [80000, 84001, 80034, 84232, 84009, 84051, 84084, 80061], "d": 1395305209944, "v": 3}, "entities": {"entities": [80000, 84001, 80034, 84232, 84009, 84051, 84084, 80061]}, "terms": {"terms": [], "d": 1395249318552, "v": 3}, "coletas": [{"terms": [], "id": 97}]}, "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQA10tlbPQBXIp4p&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.immedia.com.br%2F%2F9%2F9146_2_L.JPG", "story": "Georgevan Araujo compartilhou um link.", "updated_time": "2013-12-30T23:59:59", "from": {"name": "Georgevan Araujo", "id": "100000278536009"}, "description": "Segundo o ex-ministro da Fazenda, a prova de que o governo n\u00e3o tem nada de socialista \u00e9 que ele destruiu as suas duas principais empresas: a Petrobras e a Eletrobr\u00e1s", "caption": "www.infomoney.com.br", "privacy": {"value": ""}, "name": "\"O que o governo fez com a Petrobras foi uma trag\u00e9dia\", diz Delfim Netto", "application": {"namespace": "fbipad_", "name": "Facebook for iPad", "id": "173847642670370"}, "link": "http://www.infomoney.com.br/onde-investir/acoes/noticia/3086396/que-governo-fez-com-petrobras-foi-uma-tragedia-diz-delfim", "story_tags": {"0": [{"length": 16, "type": "user", "id": "100000278536009", "name": "Georgevan Araujo", "offset": 0}]}, "created_time": "2013-12-30T23:59:59", "_id": "100000278536009_719669731385638", "type": "link", "id": "100000278536009_719669731385638", "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif"}
```

Estava pensando em:

- Dar uma split neste arquivo em vários outros e analisar um por um
- Criar um banco de dados e colocar todas as informações no banco para uso na aplicação
- Tentar me livrar da estrutura json com uma aplicação java e ler o arquivo conforme execução

Acho que as alternativas acima não são as melhores.

Comment: Se cada linha é um JSON completo, então cada linha deve ter só uns 8KB (~= 5GB / 652339 linhas) - o que é bem tratável. Por que não separá-lo em arquivos menores? Ou então fazer um loop onde você lê linha por linha (usando um `BufferedReader` ou algo similar) e usa o Gson para interpretar cada linha. Etc. Se por outro lado for um único JSON com 5GB, então o problema é maior, mas nada intratável (me avise se for o caso, e tento formular uma resposta).

Comment: é apenas um arquivo de 5gb, estava pensando em fazer dessa forma com o BufferedReader

Comment: Encontrei [esse post](http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/) mostrando como fazer usando a biblioteca Jackson (o link no artigo exige senha, mas acho que [esse projeto no Github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) se trata da mesma biblioteca). É um pouco semelhante à [API SAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) do Java (para XMLs), mas me parece um tanto mais conveniente (pois permite ler determinados sub-elementos como um todo, se você quiser, mas lendo o "grosso" do arquivo na forma de *stream*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como a minha verdadeira necessidade nesse Json era de algumas tags, o que eu utilizei foi uma leitura de elemento por elemento em cada iteração, de acordo com a necessidade de uso. Para isso utilizei a jackson Json API. O meu código está abaixo pegando apenas as tags `title, url, text, entidades` do referido Json acima:

```
public class BrutoNewsJsonParser {

    JsonFactory factory;
    JsonParser jp;
    JsonToken current;

    public BrutoNewsJsonParser() {
        factory = new JsonFactory();
        jp = null;

        String path = "/home/nicolas/Documentos/X9dadosIC/Bruto/news_jul_dez_2013.json";

        try {
            jp = factory.createJsonParser(new File(path));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrutoNewsJsonParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public News ler() {
        EntidadesReader er = new EntidadesReader();
        String title = null, url = null, text = null;
        LinkedList<String> entidades = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean controleEntidades = true;

        int contador = 0;

        try {
            current = jp.nextToken();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrutoNewsJsonParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        if (current == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            contador++;
        }

        while (contador != 0) {
            try {
                String namefield = jp.getCurrentName();
                if ("title".equals(namefield)) {
                    title = jp.getText();
                } else if ("url".equals(namefield)) {
                    url = jp.getText();
                } else if ("text".equals(namefield)) {
                    text = jp.getText();
                } else if ("entities".equals(namefield) && controleEntidades) {
                    if (current == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
                        controleEntidades = false;
                        current = jp.nextToken();
                        while (current != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                            entidades.add(er.traduzir(Integer.parseInt(jp.getText())));
                            current = jp.nextToken();
                        }
                    }
                }

                current = jp.nextToken();
                if (current == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                    contador--;
                } else if (current == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    contador++;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(current.asString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            jp.nextToken();
        } catch (JsonParseException j) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrutoNewsJsonParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return new News(title, url, text, entidades);
    }
}
```

Com isso, a cada chamada do método Ler ele fornece um elemento adicional.

Answer (score 2):

O banco de dados é provavelmente a melhor solução, pois:

- Ele é feito para trabalhar com quantidades enormes de dados;
- 5GB é muito dado para ser mantido em memória, especialmente em Java;
- Se o dado precisar ser reutilizado, será necessário realizar todo o processo de interpretação, etc dos dados, o que sem dúvida irá levar tempo.

Não conheço uma ferramenta específica que consiga manipular tantos dados assim, ou que se gabe de ser capaz de manipular tantos dados. Mas, a não ser que você possua mais de 4^31 registros em um único nível da sua árvore de objetos, memória suficiente na sua máquina e configurar o Java para ter um limite na heap realmente grande (8GB+), não vejo problemas.

Um detalhe a ser observado que pode facilitar muito: se seu arquivo for composto apenas por linhas como o descrito, e nada mais, se quer separadas por vírgula, e cada linha for um Json completo, você pode processar linha a linha como sendo um arquivo Json, e então enviar a linha para o banco de dados, eliminando o problema de memória citado anteriormente, com a vantagem de ser razoavelmente simples de ser feito.